# Javascript promt to cancel an action

Tags: javascript, php, button, submit, prompt

I have a table of users.

There is a button to delete a user.

When I click the `Delete` button I want to display a dialog that gives the user the option to cancel the deletion.

```
<button  class='btn btn-danger' title='Delete User' name='action' value='deleteUser'>
```

My web application uses:

- php
- c9.io

Comment: <button  class='btn btn-danger' title='Delete User' name='action' value='deleteUser'>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm):

```
if (window.confirm('Do you really want to delete the selected user?')) {
  // handle delete
}
```